# BASH: Best architecture for reading from two input streams

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, io, subprocess

Simple script here:

**a)** constantly read from a socket and store values in an associative array
**b)** constantly read values from stdin and respond t/f if they already exist in the associative array

a & b are random events, not associated in any way.

The trick is accessing the array from both subprocesses (since putting a process in the background spawns it as a subprocess)

I'm thinking through the best strategy, and a few ideas occur, but I wonder if anyone has anything better in mind:

**1)** redirect the input from socket to stdin as a subprocess and handle both inputs in one while loop (data sizes are small, <30 characters, so I guess they will remain atomic?).
**2)** read the socket, then STDIN with small (0.1?) timeout values on read so as to mimic non-blocking I/O.
**3)** UPDATE: write the socket data to a file (actually have the other process write it directly to a file), then each time a request comes in to check if the value exists, process the entries in the file, adding them to the array (use file locking).

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea.  Is there a reason to do it in bash as opposed to another language?

Comment: Good question. No, no good reason to use bash over another language. Bash is simple and small, that's the only reason (and I've got 5 other other bash scripts doing similar authentication/logging/user management tasks so it's nice to maintain a uniform platform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash is not the right tool for this.  This problem is typically solved using the [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) system calls, which allow you to wait on multiple file descriptors simultaneously without spinning.  Bash does not have an interface to either of those.

I'd recommend using a scripting language such as Python or Perl (whatever you're comfortable with, really) that provides an interface with `select` or `poll` (e.g. Python's [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) module).

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on that. You're right. After looking into this more, and being a java guy, I'm going to pick up groovy and take the effort to do this task in groovy. It's been on my wishlist to learn for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is fully practical and atomic enough in the described context, but using a client / server model and named pipes it's possible to create a while-loop that can distinguish between lines coming from a fifo or `stdin`.

The server constantly reads lines from a socket (`/tmp/to`) as well as lines from `stdin` (which is being redirected to the server via `/tmp/to`).

However, lines from `stdin` get marked by the `del` byte (`\177`) to be the first byte of the line.

Then the (backgrounded) client while-loop uses this first-byte-of-line to distinguish lines of different origin.

```
# terminal window 1

# server
(
rm -f /tmp/to /tmp/from
mkfifo /tmp/to /tmp/from
while true; do 
  while IFS="" read -r -d $'\n' line; do 
    printf '%s\n' "${line}"
  done </tmp/to >/tmp/from &
  bgpid=$!
  exec 3>/tmp/to
  exec 4</tmp/from
  trap "kill -TERM $bgpid; exit" 0 1 2 3 13 15
  wait "$bgpid"
  echo "restarting..."
done
) &
serverpid=$!

# client
(
exec 3>/tmp/to;
exec 4</tmp/from;
while IFS="" read -r -d $'\n' <&4 line; do
  if [[ "${line:0:1}" == $'\177' ]]; then 
    printf 'line from stdin: %s\n' "${line:1}"
  else       
    printf 'line from fifo: %s\n' "$line"
  fi
done &
trap "kill -TERM $"'!; exit' 1 2 3 13 15
while IFS="" read -r -d $'\n' line; do
  # can we make it atomic?
  # sleep 0.5
  # dd if=/tmp/to iflag=nonblock of=/dev/null  # flush fifo
  printf '\177%s\n' "${line}"
done >&3
) 
#kill -TERM $serverpid


# terminal window 2
echo hello > /tmp/to
```