# redirect nohup stdout and flush

Tags: linux

I want to use nohup and redirect stdout to a file but I do not need a archive I just want to be able to interactively view the current stdout. I am thinking I can redirect the stdout to a file to for it to be flushed after each output

???
nohup ruby myapp.rb > output.log &

interactly view the output
tail -F ./output.log

Comment: You'll need to be more clear on that. If I correctly understand your problem, the commands you posted do exactly what you want. `tail -f` is designed to let you see what is *currently* happening in your log file.

Comment: also, what kind of output is your ruby script producing? Does this output data describe a state of your program and you want to see only the latest state update?

Comment: What my goal is to avoid the log file becoming to large, the app is saving to db at the end of the task this logging is just for live monitoring. So I am wondering if overwriting the log file each time is a good idea and if so how do I do it. The tail command does the job of viewing the file live but I notice it takes a few moments and updates multiple lines at a time and not a line at a time

Comment: The stdout from the ruby app is only output from the puts commands at each various steps in the program and yes it is only the latest state update

Comment: Avoiding large log file can be addressed by rotating your logs via the `logrotate` program. If you want to monitor the size of your log file you can do so programmatically in your ruby app and then log directly to a file (you'd have to implement a kind of internal logrotate in your prog). If you don't care about loss of some historic data in your log take look at my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to take a look at my answer to another question here:
[Linux non-blocking fifo (on demand logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360473/linux-non-blocking-fifo-on-demand-logging/7620387#7620387).

Assuming that by now you've got the `ftee` program ready, if you call your app like this:

`$ mkfifo /tmp/mylog`

`$ nohup ruby myapp.rb 2>&1 | tee output.log | ftee /tmp/mylog &`

you'll get:

- full output log int the file `output.log`
- current output of your app available on demand via the `/tmp/mylog` fifo

Now if you want to just take a peek at your prog's latest output do:

`$ cat /tmp/mylog`

Hope this helps.