# In bash, how to tail a fifo that is currently being written to, and then tail the fifo again, grepping for different text?

Tags: bash, unix, tail, fifo

I have a process that is writing to standard out, and I want to be able to monitor the output by grepping for various strings while running tail -f. One way to do this is to write to a normal file and then tail the file grepping for one string, then tail it grepping for another. However, I don't want to write to a file because this will fill up the disk, and I don't want to deal with the hassle of rotating log files.

I thought I could achieve this using fifos. E.g.,

```
mkfifo myfifo
foo > myfifo &
tail -f myfifo | grep bar
tail -f myfifo | grep baz
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. In fact, the only way I see any output when tailing is when I first execute `tail -f myfifo` and then `foo > mfifo`, but I don't want to restart foo (that's the whole point, otherwise I can just grep standard out directly and restart the process to grep for a different string). Does anyone know why this is happening or have a suggestion for how to achieve this?

Comment: Is a solution to [Linux non-blocking fifo (on demand logging)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7360473/95735) the thing you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because a [fifo is a data stream](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).  Once a piece of data is read from a FIFO, it's removed from the FIFO.  In your case, the output of `foo` that's stored in `myfifo` is being read by the first `tail -f` that `grep`s for "bar", leaving nothing for the second `tail -f`.

But you don't need to send the output of `foo` to a file at all (FIFO or otherwise).  You can just send its output [directly into `tee` and have it send that output to as many processes as you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942/how-can-i-send-the-stdout-of-one-process-to-multiple-processes-using-preferably).  For example:

```
$ foo | tee >(grep -o bar) >(grep -o baz) >/dev/null
```

Or if you're just using `grep`, you can use `-e` as many times as you want on the output:

```
$ foo | grep -e bar -e baz
```

Comment: +1 thanks, this is useful, but in my case I don't necessarily know what I will be grepping beforehand. What I was hoping to do was have a way of grepping the output of a long-running process when I see something I want to pull out. Regarding your comment about the fact that a fifo is a data stream, does that prevent it from being read by another process even after the first reader is killed (e.g., tail -f foo | grep bar <CTRL>-C tail -f foo | grep baz)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different grep syntax:

```
tail -f myfifo | grep -e 'pattern1' -e  'pattern2' -e 'pattern3'
```

I think you want both to happen at the same time on the same output stream, right?

Otherwise you could play with tee

```
tail -f myfifo | tee -a somefile | grep bar
grep foo somefile
```