# Named Pipe in C++ Linux check if buffer is full

Tags: c++

I have two C++ Programs communicating over named pipes (generated with mkfifo()).

After some time the writing program hangs. I think the buffer of FIFO is full.
Is it possible to check before writing to FIFO if buffer is full?

Thanks in advance!

Ruben

Comment: Try to `write` after setting `O_NONBLOCK` option? http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe Or `poll` and check for `POLLOUT`? http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll

Answer (score 2):

From [`pipe` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) :

> If a process attempts to write to a full pipe (see below), then
>   write(2) blocks until sufficient data has been read from the pipe to
>   allow the write to complete.

The solution is to open the pipe specifying the `O_NONBLOCK` flag (see [`open` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)).

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the `O_NONBLOCK` writing into a named fifo will lead to a out-of-memory-problem on linux:

I made a little experiment, what will happen, when the writer process...

- sets the process signal for broken pipe (`SIGPIPE`) to ignore,
- opens a named pipe with `O_NONBLOCK`
- and then writes a lot of stuff into that pipe.

This is actually integrating the idea of the [ftee-program posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620387) in the writer program itself.

On the other side, i will read out the content of the named fifo after quite a while into a file and examine it - thereby i mean "after the writer process has produced way more than 64K of data".

result is, that the file contains all the output of the writer process - this proves that way more than 64K have been buffered by linux.

This poses some questions to me:

- is there another limit beyond the 64K named pipe buffer size?
- or willl it increase until linux runs out of memory?

Background: - that is my writer program `writer.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Fcntl;

my $fifo_name = '/tmp/fifo1';

sub daemon()
{
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid < 0) { die "fork(): $! \r\n"; }    
    if ($pid > 0) { exit(0); }
    close(STDIN);
    close(STDOUT);
}

sub main()
{
    `mkfifo $fifo_name`;
    $SIG{'PIPE'}    = "IGNORE"; # ignoring SIGPIPE
    my $fifo_fh = undef;
    sysopen($fifo_fh, $fifo_name, O_NONBLOCK | O_RDWR) or die $!;

    my $n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        my $line = "This is line $n...\n";
        syswrite($fifo_fh, $line, length($line));
        select(undef, undef, undef, 0.01); # sleep 1/100 second
        $n++;
    }
}

daemon();
main();
```

... and thats what i tested:

```
$ ./writer.pl
```

... wait a while ...

```
$ cat /tmp/fifo1 > dump.txt
```

... since this will never terminate, hit Ctrl-C after a while, then

```
$ less dump.txt
This is line 0...
This is line 1...
This is line 2...
...
This is line 61014...
This is line 61015...
```

All output of writer.pl since the beginning was stored somewhere!