# UNIX/Linux idiomatic way of reporting the state of a daemon

Tags: linux, unix, logging

There is my daemon that sends and receives data via TCP and UDP. Logical connection is often a group of such streams.

I'm going to make a web page to report the types of these connections and how much data has been transfered. Can't do that by just calling `netstat`, because it's hard to figure out which connection is which, especially with UDP that can change ports. So, the daemon should accumulate the statistics.

I don't want to put the web server inside the daemon. Don't want to write statistics constantly into a file.

The good idea is used in `/proc` kernel filesystem, where the reads on files from that filesystem invoke functions in the application. It works on-demand. Would be nice to have something like that.

Are there any examples of some existing UNIX/Linux daemons that have such requirements? What do they do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `/proc` files are usually only defined to read and set Kernel parameters, not those of daemons.

[Docker uses a unix socket (usually on `/var/run/docker.sock`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/), which accepts HTTP requests and implements a REST API. This is handy for your report application, but obviously an overhead for your daemon.

You could also create a named pipe for your daemon, e.g. in `/var/run/myd.info` to which you periodically, or on demand, send your information as text.

There is already an [implementation of a named pipe writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360473/linux-non-blocking-fifo-on-demand-logging) that does not break on `SIGPIPE` (the signal when the other end has stopped reading the pipe, i.e. when you send an `EOF`).

Comment: I'm looking into DBus. Worth?

Comment: Yes, that's another alternative. Its more sophisticated than "just a pipe" though, more like the socket API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own /proc file and 'write' data to it.
It's a common way, I can remember SCST which allows you to read and even control daemon resources using their own /proc/ branch.

Take a look here: http://www.crashcourse.ca/introduction-linux-kernel-programming/lesson-11-adding-proc-files-your-modules-part-1

But you will need to create a kernel module with your daemon to use this feature.

Maybe sqlite database and some simple API on your daemon is an option here?