# Streaming video using a non-blocking FIFO in linux/bash

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, mkfifo

I am trying to accomplish the following objectives:

- Write video from my Raspberry Pi Camera to disk without any interference from streaming
- Stream the same video through the network optimizing latency

It is important streaming does not interfere with the video being written to disk, since network connection may be unstable, such as WiFi router may be out of range, etc.

To accomplish that, the first thing I have tried is the following:

```
#Receiver side
FPS="30"
netcat -l -p 5000 | mplayer -vf scale -zoom -xy 1280 -fps $FPS -cache-min 50 -cache 1024 - &
```

---

```
#RPi side
FPS="30"
mkfifo netcat_fifo
raspivid -t 0 -md 5 -fps $FPS -o - | tee --output-error=warn netcat_fifo > $video_out &
cat netcat_fifo | netcat -v 192.168.0.101 5000 &> $netcat_log &
```

And the streaming works very well. However, when I switch off the router, simulating a problem with the network, my $video_out is cut. I think this is due to the back-pressure from the netcat_fifo.

I found a solution here at stackexchange concerning a non-blocking FIFO, by replacing tee by ftee:

[Linux non-blocking fifo (on demand logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360473/linux-non-blocking-fifo-on-demand-logging)

It now prevents my $video_out from being affected by the streaming, but the streaming itself is very unstable. The best results were using the following script:

```
#RPi side
FPS="30"
MULTIPIPE="ftee"
mkfifo netcat_fifo
raspivid -t 0 -md 5 -fps $FPS -o - | ./${MULTIPIPE} netcat_fifo > $video_out &
cat netcat_fifo | mbuffer --direct -t -s 2k 2> $mbuffer_log | netcat -v 192.168.0.101 5000 &> $netcat_log &
```

When I check the mbuffer log, I diagnose a FIFO that remains most of the time empty, but has peaks of 99-100% utilization. During these peaks, my mplayer receiver-side has many errors decoding the video and takes about 5 seconds to recover itself. After this interval, the mbuffer log shows again an empty FIFO.
The empty->full->empty goes on and on.

I have two questions:

- Am I using the correct approach to solve my problem?
- If so, how could I render my streaming more robust while keeping the $video_out file intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a little attempt at this and it seems to work pretty solidly on my Raspberry Pi 3. It is pretty well commented so it should be quite easy to understand, but you can always ask if there are any questions.

Basically there are 3 threads:

- main program - it constantly reads its `stdin` from `raspivid` and cyclically puts the data into a bunch of buffers
- disk writer thread - it constantly cycles through the list of buffers waiting for the next one to become full. When the buffer is full, it writes the contents to disk, marks the buffer as written and moves onto the next one
- fifo writer thread - it constantly cycles through the list of buffers waiting for the next one to become full. When the buffer is full, it writes the contents to the fifo, flushes the fifo to reduce lag and marks the buffer as written and moves onto the next one. Errors are ignored.

---

So, here is the code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp
// Mark Setchell
//
// Read video stream from "raspivid" and write (independently) to both disk file
// and stdout - for onward netcatting to another host.
//
// Compiles with:
//    g++ main.cpp -o main -lpthread
//
// Run on Raspberry Pi with:
//    raspivid -t 0 -md 5 -fps 30 -o - | ./main video.h264 | netcat -v 192.168.0.8 5000
//
// Receive on other host with:
//    netcat -l -p 5000 | mplayer -vf scale -zoom -xy 1280 -fps 30 -cache-min 50 -cache 1024 -
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFSZ    65536
#define NBUFS    64

class Buffer{
   public:
   int bytes=0;
   std::atomic<int> NeedsWriteToDisk{0};
   std::atomic<int> NeedsWriteToFifo{0};
   unsigned char data[BUFSZ];
};

std::vector<Buffer> buffers(NBUFS);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is the DiskWriter thread.
// It loops through all the buffers waiting in turn for each one to become ready
// then writes it to disk and marks the buffer as written before moving to next
// buffer.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void DiskWriter(char* filename){
   int bufIndex=0;

   // Open output file
   int fd=open(filename,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP);
   if(fd==-1)
   {
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open output file" << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   bool Error=false;
   while(!Error){

      // Wait for buffer to be filled by main thread
      while(buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToDisk!=1){
   //      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
      }

      // Write to disk
      int bytesToWrite=buffers[bufIndex].bytes;
      int bytesWritten=write(fd,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&buffers[bufIndex].data),bytesToWrite);
      if(bytesWritten!=bytesToWrite){
         std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to write to disk" << std::endl;
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // Mark buffer as written
      buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToDisk=0;

      // Move to next buffer
      bufIndex=(bufIndex+1)%NBUFS;
   }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is the FifoWriter thread.
// It loops through all the buffers waiting in turn for each one to become ready
// then writes it to the Fifo, flushes it for reduced lag, and marks the buffer
// as written before moving to next one. Errors are ignored.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void FifoWriter(){
   int bufIndex=0;

   bool Error=false;
   while(!Error){

      // Wait for buffer to be filled by main thread
      while(buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToFifo!=1){
    //     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
      }

      // Write to fifo
      int bytesToWrite=buffers[bufIndex].bytes;
      int bytesWritten=write(STDOUT_FILENO,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&buffers[bufIndex].data),bytesToWrite);
      if(bytesWritten!=bytesToWrite){
         std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to write to fifo" << std::endl;
      }
      // Try to reduce lag
      fflush(stdout);

      // Mark buffer as written
      buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToFifo=0;

      // Move to next buffer
      bufIndex=(bufIndex+1)%NBUFS;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
   int bufIndex=0;

   if(argc!=2){
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Usage " << argv[0] << " filename" << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   char * filename = argv[1];

   // Start disk and fifo writing threads in parallel
   std::thread tDiskWriter(DiskWriter,filename);
   std::thread tFifoWriter(FifoWriter);

   bool Error=false;
   // Continuously fill buffers from "raspivid" on stdin. Mark as full and
   // needing output to disk and fifo before moving to next buffer.
   while(!Error)
   {
      // Check disk writer is not behind before re-using buffer
      if(buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToDisk==1){
         std::cerr << "ERROR: Disk writer is behind by " << NBUFS << " buffers" << std::endl;
      }

      // Check fifo writer is not behind before re-using buffer
      if(buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToFifo==1){
         std::cerr << "ERROR: Fifo writer is behind by " << NBUFS << " buffers" << std::endl;
      }

      // Read from STDIN till buffer is pretty full
      int bytes;
      int totalBytes=0;
      int bytesToRead=BUFSZ;
      unsigned char* ptr=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&buffers[bufIndex].data);
      while(totalBytes<(BUFSZ*.75)){
         bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO,ptr,bytesToRead);
         if(bytes<=0){
            Error=true;
            break;
         }
         ptr+=bytes;
         totalBytes+=bytes;
         bytesToRead-=bytes;
      }

      // Signal buffer ready for writing
      buffers[bufIndex].bytes=totalBytes;
      buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToDisk=1;
      buffers[bufIndex].NeedsWriteToFifo=1;

      // Move to next buffer
      bufIndex=(bufIndex+1)%NBUFS;
   }
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer, Mark. I have done some changes to adapt it to my requirements. Instead of outputting to stdout, it accepts directly a UDP or TCP socket. The code is uploaded here:
https://bitbucket.org/gleisonstorto/rocket/src/886f8a73e6b6c35ddbdf7dc6ccfddaef7a958ea6/raspivid_tee.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Cool - glad it works for you. Thank you for sharing your updates. Good luck with your project!